# Uploaded module not appearing in list

Tags: add-on, module

I have created a module on my local installation which appears correctly in the Modules list. I can install and uninstall it without a problem.

However, when I upload it via FTP to the remote web server, it does not appear in the list of Modules. I uploaded it into the correct location (/system/expressionengine/third_party/) and the folder structure is correct.

Has anyone else come across this problem?

Comment: It turns out I did something stupid - the site was moved to a new server and I was uploading the files to the previous server *facepalm*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As unlikely as it sounds, if you're sure the the location is correct I'd try checking permissions. I've run across a few times where either the directories or the add-on files themselves were not set to be readable at all and therefore EE didn't recognize they were there.

Comment: I'm accepting this answer as, although my problem was my own stupidity, it's good advice for others.

Answer (score 0):

As Mike mentions above check permissions as that can be the main problem here. The only other thing I can think of would be some erroneous white space at the end of a closing **?>** PHP tag in one (or possibly more) of the modules files. That could also cause the problem.